# doubt regarding payoff calculation

Tags: probability

The following is a part of a bigger question :

> The player pays £1 to play a game and P(win) = 11/120 , (so P(loss) =
>   109/120)
>
> The maximum prize fund the banker should allocate for winning in this
>   game would be £10 before they would expect to incur a loss.
>
> Note that any payout will be a whole number of pounds and also
>   includes the original £1 paid to play the game, so in the example
>   given the player actually wins £9.

Based on my understanding given no loss criteria we should have an equation of the form :

x*P(win) - y*P(loss) = 0 : where x and y are payoffs for win and lose respectively which gives x/y = 109/11

Can someone explain how the value of £9 ( or £10) has been calculated in the question or at which step I am making a mistake .

Comment: A good start would be to use an inequality rather than an equality, which then allows for the fact that fractions of pounds are not allowed. $xP(win) - yP(loss)\geq 0$.  I haven't done the math but I suspect it will show that £11 would break the inequality.

Comment: Your $\frac{109}{11}$ is between $9$ and $10$ so adding the £$1$ entry fee gives a number between $10$ and $11$ for a fair prize.  If you are restricted to integers ...